# Send SMS programmatically using Amazon SNS service in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, sms, amazon-sns

I am working on an Events app where I send notification to registered users whenever a new event has been created by the host. I want to send out an SMS to the subscribed users of my app, 30 minutes before the event starts.

I have looked up on the internet and saw that there are 2 methods to do this- by using Twilio and Amazon SNS as the message server. I am however not able to integrate this with react native.

I just want to send out SMS's to multiple users programmatically without any manual intervention. The SMS notification for the event should be sent out 30 minutes before the event starts. The DB has the event time and all details.

Edit: I am able to do this with node.js but I am not able to get its equivalent for react-native using expo. As my whole mobile app, is based on expo's react-native. I have to use the same for the SMS part.

Comment: I don;t think that you should do it with reactNative. You should use some server to send the SMS messages, not the client app.

Comment: Hi  Vladyslav Matviienko, the server I am thinking of using is twilio in which you create an account with the security keys and a message will be sent from there.

Comment: Ok, looks like I should explain why I think that using react native for that is bad idea. There are many reasons, but the most important is: If you are going to do that with react native, you are going to store your secret key, or login/password for SMS gateway service inside APK, which is easy to decompile, extract your secret information, and use your SMS gateway to send own SMS.

Comment: **But** if you are still OK with that - you just need to do certain network requests to the Amazon SNS API from react-native to send SMS. They should have the rest API, and you don't need to use any react-native-specific SDK for it.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it in React Native because I am developing my mobile app on that. I looked up the Amazon SNS docs and I believe  that it too has support with Node.js only. I didn't really think about the security issues at the moment.